# Combinatorics counts outcomes, what mathematics lists outcomes?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Since I've been learning combinatorics the past few days I've constantly found myself wanting to implement the combinatorics I've learned in various ways(mostly by writing software that analizes each outcome). However, a lot of those times I'm required to know the *value* of each outcome, and when the number of outcomes becomes large enough I can't *really* write down every outcome.

With some effort I can probably create some algorithm suited for my particular listing requirement, however I'm curious whether there has been made a study of the mathematics of listing outcomes in general?

Is there such a branch of mathematics or anything *similar* to that?

Comment: Is there any particular structure you're interested in listing? I'd say that combinatorics very much deals with this sort of thing when it can and sometimes listing is easier than counting or vice versa.

Comment: @Meelo That's the thing, I'm not thinking of any particular structure. More curious whether there exists some mathematics that takes a _general_ approach to listing, regardless of what is being listed(if that's even possible, I don't know?).

Comment: @Meelo I've edited my question to be slightly more general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The combinatorics you're learning is specifically enumerative combinatorics. There's also structural combinatorics, which deals with possibilities and restrictions on the objects with which we do combinatorics. The two work well together-- enumerating objects can give insights into their structure, and knowing the allowed structures of objects makes them easier to count.

For example, Kuratowski's theorem, that planar graphs can't have a $K_5$ or a $K_{3,3}$ minor, is a structural result. This theorem makes it possible to count the number of planar graphs on $n$ vertices, an enumerative result.

In enumerative combinatorics, there are two ways to get results: find a way to count what you want, or find a bijection between what you want to count and a known set of objects. Either way, listing the objects isn't a terribly big challenge, because if you can count them, you should have an argument to say what they are.

Thus, you're using computer algebra software, you should be able to tell it to print the things you want according to your combinatorial proof and leave it to it. I don't think listing things is a terribly interesting problem, and it's not a branch of mathematics so much as it is programming. That's not to say that compiling a set of examples doesn't have tremendous value in mathematics, but compiling them all is a bit excessive.

Comment: That structural combinatorics you mention, it seems interesting, can you link me to any online available material and/or popular books on the subject? I agree that listing objects isn't terribly interesting or too much of a challenge, but since I'm new to mathematics I'm not going to just accept that without asking around a bit.

Comment: I'd say that any introductory text to graph theory will have good structural problems. You may also be interested in matroid theory.

Comment: I found a book titled "Combinatorics and Graph Theory (Undergraduate Texts in Mathematics)", that seems like something I'm looking for. After a quick scan of Matroid Theory on wikipedia, it would seem I need linear algebra and graph theory as a prerequisite. So I'll have to put in some work before learning any of that. I'm not familiar enough with the terminology to know exactly what I can use Matroid Theory for, do you mind giving me a basic example?

Comment: I don't know that well enough to give you a good answer. Basically, they take the notions of dependence (redundancy) from linear algebra and graph theory and apply it to lots of other concepts, so matroids are useful for optimization.

Comment: Okay, thank you nonetheless.